# In what locally compact abelian groups does $\mathbb{Q}$ embed densely?

Tags: number-theory, abelian-groups, harmonic-analysis

I know that there is classification of local fields, but here is a closely related question: Can the additive group of $\mathbb{Q}$ be a proper dense subgroup of a locally compact abelian group, whose topology is complete, other than the p adic numbers or the reals?  I think of this question more as a collection, and I guess I will have to try out various examples here.

1.Example by MattE: Consider $\alpha =(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, then the map $q \mapsto q \alpha:= ( q \alpha_1, \dots, q \alpha_n)$ becomes  dense in the $n$ torus, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{Z}^n$, actually even more it becomes equidistributed in the following sense 
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n \leq N} f(n \alpha) \rightarrow \int\limits_{\mathbb{R^N} / \mathbb{Z}^n} f( x) \mathrm{d} x.$$

Comment: By strong approximation, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}_{v}$ for any valuation $v$ on $\mathbb{Q}$      http://modular.math.washington.edu/books/ant/ant/node108.html

Comment: @Theo: One of those is indecomposable, the other not!

Comment: @Steve: Thanks, silly me.

Comment: @late_learner : Good point...

Comment: As for groups in which $\mathbb{Q}$ is a lattice here's a stupid example. Consider any compact group $C$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ in the discrete topology. Then $\mathbb{Q}$ is a lattice in the locally compact group $\mathbb{Q} \times C.$

Comment: Okay that's what happens exactly for the finite adeles, that is $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q} \prod\limits_p \mathbb{Z}_p$, so my 2nd questions seems stupid in retrospective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can surely be embedded densely in many such groups.  E.g. it can be embedded into $(S^1)^n$ for any $n$.  (Here $S^1$ is the circle group.)

To see this, choose an element $\alpha$ in $(S^1)^n$ whose powers are dense
in $(S^1)^n$.

Now for inductively, for each integer $m$, choose $\alpha_m$ such that
$\alpha_m^m = \alpha$, in a compatible way (i.e. so that if $m' = d m,$
then $\alpha_{m'}^d = \alpha_m$).  Then the $\alpha_m$ together generate
a copy of $\mathbb Q$ inside $(S^1)^n$, which will be dense.

(A little more succintly, I am using the fact that $(S^1)^n$ is divisible,
hence injective, to extend the embedding $\mathbb Z \hookrightarrow (S^1)^n$
to an embedding $\mathbb Q \hookrightarrow (S^1)^n$.)

Another way to think about this example, when $n = 2$ say, is that we take a line with irrational slope in $(S^1)^2$; this gives a dense copy of $\mathbb R$, which contains inside it a dense copy of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: So, I guess you use something like $q \mapsto (e^{iq}, \pi^{iq})$ and there like. nice example.

Comment: Couldn't you just extend the embedding $f : \mathbb{Z} \to (S^1)^n$ by denoting $\alpha = (e^{i \theta_1}, \ldots, e^{i \theta_n})$ and setting $f(q) = (e^{i q\theta_1}, \ldots, e^{i q\theta_n})$ ?

Comment: @Joel: Dear Joel, Yes, you're right!  (I just bashed out the first thing that came to mind.)  Thanks, and best wishes,

Answer (score 0):

The torsion subgroup $tor(G)$ of the $1$-dimensional compact connected abelian dual $G$ of any rank-one torsion-free abelian group $X$ is dense in $G$. It follows that the topological divisible hull $\mathbb{Q}\,tor(G)$ in $G$ of $tor(G)$ is dense in $G$ and contains a continuum of algebraically isomorphic copies of $\mathbb{Q}$.